# View over view breaks hierarchical

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, tableview, uisegmentedcontrol

I'm using [MZFormSheetPresentationController](https://github.com/m1entus/MZFormSheetPresentationController) to show as "pop-up" a ViewController2 (embedded in a Navigation controller as suggested) over a ViewController1.

My ViewController1 has a searchbar, a UISegmentedControl and a tableview:

[image: Image1]

When user clicks on the searchbar bookmark button, pop-up is shown.

[image: Image2]

I'd like to close the pop-up when user clicks on the done button and it works great using **self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)** method but I'm looking for more. I'd like to present again ViewController1 so tableView will reload data.
I tried with:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        print("Dismissed")

        //goToTickets
        let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myTabBar") as! UITabBarController
        self.presentViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

but I get this error:

> Warning: Attempt to present  on  whose view is not in the window hierarchy!

Pop-up disappears but I can't present ViewController.

How can I do?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

This is my ViewController2 with identifier "navigationFilter"

[image: Image4]

and my tabBar:

[image: Image5]

Answer (score 1):

When you are in the middle of dismissing you are trying to present next ViewController, you have to wait for completion handler and then present next view controller like this:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
    let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myTabBar") as! UITabBarController
    self.presentViewController(next, animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

Comment: I tried but I still get the error, I wrote this code in viewController2

Comment: You have problem somewhere in your view hierarchy, MZFormSheetPresentationController works same as normal modal presentation controller, so you should try to use normal presentation and then use MZFormSheetPresentationController.

Comment: I updated my question with the structure of my app. I really don't know how I get this error..

Comment: You are trying to present on view controller which is not longer on view Hierarchy TabBarController ----/ --> FormSheet , and you are trying probably to preent on FormSheet, you must present again on TabBarController, and you could use for this self.presentingViewController property.

Comment: I am sorry to steal your time, but it is very important for me to understand how it works. I need to call "self.presentingViewController" within - before or after the method self.dismissViewControllerAnimated? Thanks

Comment: I tried this within dismissViewControllerAnimated -> let next = self.presentingViewController  self.presentViewController(next!, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: self.presentingViewController.presentViewController(..)

Comment: Using self.presentingViewController.presentViewController I got nil on the "next" value

Comment: I can't let empty the "(..)", what should I put here? Maybe it works